# Sending message to EventHub with Java client fails with javax.jms.JMSException

Tags: java, azure-eventhub

I'm writing my first app to send and receive from EventHub. I'm following the example provided in [Azure doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-java-storm-getstarted/).

My servicebus.properties file looks like this.

```
connectionfactory.SBCF = amqps://SendRule:BLAH..blah@mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/?sync-publish=false
queue.EventHub = eventhub1
```

My sender code looks like this

```
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "servicebus.properties");
    Context context = new InitialContext(env);

    ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("SBCF");
    Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("EventHub");
    Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
    Session sendSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageProducer sender = sendSession.createProducer(queue);
```

I'm getting an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target: eventhub1
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.MessageProducerImpl.<init>(MessageProducerImpl.java:69)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.createProducer(SessionImpl.java:293)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.createProducer(SessionImpl.java:57)
    at com.commvault.azure.Sender.main(Sender.java:39)
```

When I googled for solution, I get help on ServiceBus Queues and the connection string used is of format [username]:[password]:[namespace]. Don't find any help on EventHub.

Any suggestion what is missing?